# Sequence manipulation

Tags: r, ggplot2, seq

I have a matrix that is equivalent to a 96-well plate commonly used in microbiology. In that matrix I randomized 12 treatments each 8 times. I printed a kind of guide in order to follow the patten in the lab easily, and then after measurements I merged the randomized plate to the data.

```
cipPlate <- c(rep(c(seq(0,50,5),"E"),8)); cipPlate
rcipPlate <- array(sample(cipPlate),dim=c(8,12),dimnames=dimna); rcipPlate
platecCIP <- melt(rcipPlate); platecCIPbbCIP
WellCIP <- paste(platecCIP$Var1,platecSTR$Var2,sep=''); WellCIP
bbCIP <- data.frame(Well=WellCIP,ID=platecCIP$value); bbCIP
```

That works fine, except that the numbers in the sequence created for this are characters instead of integers. Then when i try to use ggplo2 to plot this with the measurements instead of plotting in the x -axis (o,5,10,15,...,50) it goes (0,10,15,...,45,5,50)

Is there a way to avoid this, or to make the numbers inside these sequence to represent the actual number as an integer instead of a character

BTW: sorry for the clumpsy code, I'm not an expert and it works good enough so that i can use it further.

Comment: `bbCIP$ID <- as.integer(as.character(bbCIP$ID))`, but all `E` values will become `NA`. Then you can replace them with any value you want - `bbCIP$ID[is.na(bbCIP$ID)] <- 1000`

Comment: You cannot mix numeric and character modes in a matrix. Use a distinctive numeric value instead of "E".